# WordPress 4.0 fresh install admin not working

Tags: wordpress

I did a fresh WordPress installation today and a lot of issues were happening.

- Themes not exchangeable;
- Settings checkboxes not working;
- No icons in administration;
- etc.

A lot of posts are talking about rights, and theme problems, but it does not seems like it.

So I activated Javascript debugging and found out it was a script issue.

Then searching with this information I found that adding this in the wp-config.php file fixes the problem.

```
define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false );
```

It seems to be an old issue, does anyone know if it is related to something else than only the scripts concatenation code?

Comment: If you see Javascript errors in the console, yes it might possibly be that. What plugins are you using?

Comment: hi, teachPress and that's about it !